# Is there a way to explicitely have a not-null column in a view

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, view, null

If I create a view in Oracle, the column definition's *not null* characteristic is inherited from the base table:

```
create table tq84_t (
  col_1   number,
  col_2   varchar2(15) not null
);

create view tq84_v as select col_1, col_2 from tq84_t;

desc tq84_v;
```

will print

```
Name            Null?    Type
--------------- -------- -----------------------------------------
COL_1                    NUMBER
COL_2           NOT NULL VARCHAR2(15)
```

Now, if the view's select statement contains a `union all`, it seems as though that characteristic is not inherited anymore:

```
drop view tq84_v;

create view tq84_v as 
  select col_1, col_2 from tq84_t where col_1 < 10 union all 
  select col_1, col_2 from tq84_t where col_2 > 20;

desc tq84_v;
```

prints:

```
Name            Null?    Type
--------------- -------- -----------------------------------------
COL_1                    NUMBER
COL_2                    VARCHAR2(15)
```

This is a bit unfortunate for my purposes. So, is there a way to explicitely state that a column be `not null` for a view in Oracle?

Note: I obviously used a simplified view defintion to demonstrate the problem, and I could re-write the view definition without using `union all`. Yet, my *actual* view defintion is much more complicated, requiring the `union all`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/clauses002.htm#i1002565):

> You can specify only unique, primary key, and foreign key constraints
> on views. However, you can define the view using the WITH CHECK OPTION
> clause, which is equivalent to specifying a check constraint for the
> view.

So it seems that there is no way to hint to the RDBMS that the underlying data (after the `UNION ALL` inline view is created) is `NOT NULL`.

This all seems a bit silly, given the `UNION`/`UNION ALL`/`INTERSECT`/`MINUS` statements all require matching datatypes!

Comment: Yes, union etc require matching datatypes, but they don't require "matching" nullability.